# how to call activity of a project in other project?

Tags: android

I am a beginner and i tried out calling an activity of the previous project(project B) in the current project(project A)..
I used this code in project A  to call project B

```
    package com.example.demo1;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View; 
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.demo2", ".NAvActivity"));
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
  }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and the manifestation file of project B is as follows

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".NAvActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

but i could not navigate to the other class. Help me solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.demo2","com.example.demo2.NAvActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Your manifest should be something like this,

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.demo2.NAvActivity"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start activity with full class name with package like below....

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**OR**

Step #1: Add an `<intent-filter>` in `AndroidMenifest.xml` to the project B activity with a custom action:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.CUSTOM_ACTION"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Step #2: Start that activity using an appropriate Intent from project A:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.CUSTOM_ACTION"));
```

Comment: I tried it but its not even allowing the app to open and is displaying the FATAL exception errors

Comment: have your replaced package name with your package name ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use Like this**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.demo.status",
            "com.demo.status.MainActivity"));

    startActivity(i);
```